# Two Angular application in One Angular project - Different features/functions between the applications

Tags: angular

I currently have 2 Angular application in 1 Angular project, they are using the same src folder but have their own index.html file. What I want to do is the app1(cpho-app) has a "Create Folder" feature which is in a component, while the app2(hhpnz-app) doesn't or is not available. Is this possible? and what would be the best approach to it? thanks!

```
<button mat-menu-item
          [adf-create-folder]="getDocumentListCurrentFolderId()"
          (success)="onFolderCreate($event)">
          <mat-icon>folder</mat-icon>
          <span>Folder</span>
</button>
```

[Here is my project structure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68iLo.png)

Comment: I don't understand why? There could only be one when you bootstrap it. Use `Modules` instead.

Comment: @penleychan what do you mean by use modules instead?